# How can I specify a command to execute like node bnlserver.js in a shell script

Tags: shell

Trying to write a shell script to run as a cron job to make sure the bnlserver.js is still running and restart if not.

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# this script checks to see if the "node bnlserver.js" program is running
# and restarts it if not

ps -ef | grep bnlserver.js

if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    node | bnlserver.js
fi

exit
```

and it didn't work.  My lousy shell scripting.  I'm sure you folks know how to do it.
So how do I fix it?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to remove at least the second pipe (`|`). You might need to specify the PATH or the full path of the node script. Besides that it kind of looks OK (however using cron is not the best solution, using "supervise" or "forever" (http://blog.risingstack.com/operating-node-in-production/)) is better.

Comment: supervise, or forever, or runit, or daemontools, or upstart, or systemd, or launchd, or (for that matter) an entry in `/etc/inittab` if you have old-school SysV init... seriously, your operating system already has *something* which will do this job for you, and do it far far better than a cronned shell script will. Don't reinvent this wheel.

Comment: See the scripts at http://smarden.org/runit/runscripts.html for examples of just how easy this could be -- if you were using `runit`, your script could contain nothing more than `exec node bnlserver.js` (after your `#!/bin/sh` line), and that's it -- `runit` would make sure only one copy of that process ran at a time, and restart it if it failed. What you have instead is incredibly fragile -- `vim bnlserver.js` would tell `ps | grep bnlserver.js` that your process was running even if it were down.

Comment: BTW -- no need at all for an `exit` at the end of your scripts; the shell does the exact same thing with no `exit` command at all as what `exit` does when passed no arguments (both exit with the status of the most recent command to be run).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! ps -ef | grep -q "[b]nlserver[.]js"; then
    node bnlserver.js
fi
```

The syntax is a bit terse, but required for accuracy. The `grep -q` command will test for match, and exit on first match. The pattern `"[b]nlserver[.]js"` is designed so as to never match the the grep search itself.

This could be made more efficient on platforms where `pgrep` is available.

NOTE: thanks to Charles Duffy for materially improving this code. His assistance does not however endorse this approach -- he prefers using supervise, forever or runit.

Comment: First, you're piping the output of `node` to `bnlserver.js`, which is definitely wrong. Second, you aren't actually _using_ `grep -c` in your answer as currently written (making it buggy). Third, `grep -c` is silly when you only want to know if the answer is zero or one-or-more; `grep -q` will give you that answer more efficiently, since it exits as soon as it finds the first match, rather than needing to read the rest of input to generate a count.

Comment: Fourth, your test syntax is wrong -- you need to have a space between the `1` and the closing `]`.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Edits applied.

Comment: Actually, from the perspective of fixing up the `grep` syntax, you'd want something more like: `if ps -ef | grep -q bnlserver.js; then` -- using `[ ]` and a subshell will result in the test always returning false, since `grep -q` communicates its result only via exit status and not via stdout. Avoiding those extra components is more efficient besides -- one less fork/wait() cycle.

Comment: That said, if targeting platforms where it's available, one might consider using `pgrep` instead of `ps | grep`, which would further improve both correctness and efficiency (this also avoids the `grep` command itself showing up in the output of `ps`, a common source of false positives; to avoid this otherwise, you might grep for `[b]nlserver[.]js`, or otherwise a regular expression which doesn't match itself; the `[.]` also prevents characters other than a literal `.` matching -- as in a regex, `.` means any character, so by default, `grep foo.js` would allow, say, `fooejs` to match).

Comment: Thanks for additional comments. Edits applied (I enjoy code golf)

Comment: Take out the `$()` here -- that reads the output of your pipeline and tries to substitute that output into another command. You don't need another command -- the exit status of the pipeline itself is what you care about.

Comment: Looks good to me, with the caveats on the approach as a whole given in my comments on the question... but at least the answer is no longer incorrect in and of itself, so retracting my downvote.

Comment: Well, *almost* no longer incorrect. If there's a file named `bnlserver.js` in the current directory where this script is run, the shell will glob-expand `[b]nlserver.js` to `bnlserver.js` before running `grep`, meaning you no longer get the protection against the grep command matching itself in the process table. Thus, the quotes I suggested earlier actually do enhance correctness.

Comment: (also, if `shopt -s nullglob` were set, an unquoted `[b]nlserver.js` would just be replaced with nothing at all rather than left in place if no such file existed. Though this option isn't enabled by default, it can often be useful in the context of a larger script, so it's somewhat safer to follow practices that are robust against it as a matter of habit).

Comment: Hmm...too many edits for me to take credit. How about you post the correct answer, I'll delete mine and up vote yours.

Comment: Naw -- I don't really like this approach as a whole, so I'd rather just contribute to implementation correctness and let you take credit. If I post an answer here, it'll be something I strongly support as a best practice.

Comment: (Oops -- rereading, I *didn't* suggest quotes earlier! `grep -q "bnlserver[.]js"` or `grep -q 'bnlserver[.]js'` will both do the job of preventing the shell from doing glob expansion, and by using at least one set of square brackets, will prevent the grep from matching itself).

Comment: Thanks for all of the help folks.  Greatly appreciated.